# Error using webdriver with headless chrome to download file

Tags: python, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use headless chrome driver to download pdf. Everything works fine when I downloaded pdf without headless chrome. Here is part of my driver setting code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
         "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}], # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
         'download.default_directory': 'download_dir' ,
         "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"}

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('"--no-sandbox"')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')

params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
driver.execute("send_command", params)
driver.get(url)
try : WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'check-pdf')))
finally:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('check-pdf').click()
```

The error shows up when I run this file in cmd.

```
[0623/130628.966:INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://s11.cnzz.com/z_stat.php?id=1261865322, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: http://utrack.hexun.com/dp/hexun_uweb.js (7)
    [0623/130628.968:INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://s11.cnzz.com/z_stat.php?id=1261865322, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: http://utrack.hexun.com/dp/hexun_uweb.js (7)
    [0623/130628.974:INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://c.cnzz.com/core.php?web_id=1261865322&t=z, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: https://s11.cnzz.com/z_stat.php?id=1261865322 (16)
    [0623/130628.976:INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://c.cnzz.com/core.php?web_id=1261865322&t=z, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: https://s11.cnzz.com/z_stat.php?id=1261865322 (16)
    [0623/130629.038:INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined", source: http://img.hexun.com/zl/hx/index/js/appDplus.js (8)
    [0623/130629.479:WARNING:render_frame_host_impl.cc(2750)] OnDidStopLoading was called twice
```

I am wondering what the error message means and how I can fix it ?

Any idea would be helpful !

Comment: those aren't errors.. it's INFO and a WARNING messages.  Can you explain the actual problem you are having.  Does it not download?

Comment: Hi @CoreyGoldberg, yes, it did not download anything for now. Can't find the reason...